# Can't open sh file

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to execute a sh file from script python.

My script python

```
os.system('sh run.sh')
```

My sh file

```
echo 'The house is blue' | /opt/palavras/por.pl > output.txt
```

Error:

> sh: 0: Cant' open run.sh

How can I fix it?

Comment: You might want to use an absolute path or a path relative to the directory from which you run the python program. As it is currently, `sh` is going to look for `run.sh` in its `$PATH`, which might differ from your execution context's `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this would run from the terminal either because you must run the file in order.  Try:

```
os.system('sh chmod +x run.sh|./run.sh')
```

instead.

See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files for details on running sh files and [how to use os.system() in python for running an shell order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357655/how-to-use-os-system-in-python-for-running-an-shell-order) for the use of `|` running in an order in a shell.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your bash script has the right permissions (i.e it is executable). In a terminal run:

```
chmod +x run.sh
```

and then try (assuming that `run.sh` is in the same directory as your python script)

```
import os
os.system('./run.sh')
```

Comment: As I thought you need to use the "or" `|` operator run in a shell order.  `os.system('chmod +x run.sh')`, `os.system('./run.sh')` doesn't do it unfortunately because this is equivalent to opening two terminals.